# SQLAlchemy: "does not link from element" error when using `(joined|subquery)load` on relationship with `secondary` parameter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

**I have the following query that works find without any form of eager loading configured:**

```py
model.DBSession.query(Content)
                .options(
                    joinedload(Content.asset_classes).
                    joinedload(Content.asset_types))
                .filter(Content.id.in_(content_ids))
                .all()
```

**And these relationships:**

```py
    asset_classes = orm.relationship(
        AssetClass,
        backref=orm.backref('content'),
        secondary=content_asset_class_ass_table
    )

    asset_types = orm.relationship(
        AssetType,
        backref=orm.backref('content'),
        secondary=content_asset_type_ass_table
    )
```

**When this query executes, it causes this error:**

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategy_options.py", line 156, in _generate_path
    "link from element '%s'" % (attr, path.entity))
ArgumentError: Attribute 'Content.asset_types' does not
    link from element 'Mapper|AssetClass|asset_classes'
```

**These are the modifications that make the query work:**

1. When removing the entire `.options()` call, it works fine, and subsequent queries are lazily executed when `result.asset_classes` or `result.asset_types` are referenced.
2. When only using *either* `joinedload(Content.asset_classes)` *or* `joinedload(Content.asset_types)`, the joining works, it just doesn't work with both at the same time, and similary when adding more `joinedload` statements for other relationship properties.

**Why do multiple `joinedload` directives not work when a single one does work?**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], i.e. actual models that can be used to verify your observations.

Answer (score 6):

The dot (`.`) between `joinedload` instances needs to be a comma (`,`) in this case.

I was also mislead by one of the ORM properties not being joinable, but the error message was terrible.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me an afternoon